# Convert binary array into pdf - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf, download

Jquery Ajax request that returns a binary array.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/documents/docDownload",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {
    responseType: "blob"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    var a = $("<a/>", {
      "href": file,
      "download": data.name || "detailPDF"
    }).appendTo('body');
    a.click();
    $(window).on('focus', function(e) {
      $('a').remove();
    });
  }
})
```

Now i need to transform the binary array in a PDF as it was originally.

A tried a bunch of situations, even transform the object as a blob object but nothing.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/documents/docDownload",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data) { // in my jQuery version you should move this out like $.ajax(...).success(function(data) {...}
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var a = $("<a/>", {
      "href": fileURL,
      "download": data.name || "detailPDF"
    }).html('download!').appendTo('body');
    a.click();
    $(window).on('focus', function(e) {
      $('a').remove();
    });
  }
})
```

**EDIT:**

After the comment i have changed the code and now it works for me.

Comment: Works! Got the pdf! But it's empty and the original one is not!

Comment: For me doesn't work! Now neither opens the PDF alone! And if i try to run the fileURL in another tab, returns me an empty pdf in the same.